# Binding jQuery scoll to a div

Tags: jquery

I am designing a fullscreen scrolling Web site. As part of this, I am trying to use the jQuery scroll() function so that if a visitor tries to scroll inside one of te sections,they are immedaitely transported to the next section if they scroll down, or the previous section if they scroll up.

In the HTML, all the sections are divs with IDs. E.g., :

```
<div id="home">
…
</div>
```

ThejQuery docs say that an ordinary div has to be scrollable in order for scroll() to be bound to it. So in the CSS I have:

```
div#home { /* And I have tried  plain 'div' */
…
overflow: scroll;  /* And I have tried 'auto' */
```

}

In the included .js file I have:

```
$( function() {
var pos = $( window ).scrollTop();
console.log( "Scroll top at " + pos );
$( '#home' ).scroll( function() {
    console.log( "Scroll event fired" );
});
```

});

Nothing appears in the console log.

If I try

```
$( window ).scroll( function() {
    console.log( "Scroll event fired" );
});
```

the message now appears in the console log, but never if I try to select a div. Can anyone tell me IF I can do what I want at all, and if so, how?

Comment: Use this... its best solution for what you want to do.... https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: Every Screamer, thank you for the suggestion. I had already investigated this. But every such solution comes with overhead. I like to write my own skeletal code!

Comment: Yes i allso provided with solution below :) that coresponds with your question

Comment: I ma sorry, Every Screamer, but your answer sekects "div". I can do that too, I need a solution that selects a named div by its ID.

Comment: i will update my answer

Comment: Early Screamer, I have been programming in JavaScriot since the 1990s, and in JQuery since it came out. What I said about jusr usung "div" as a selector was in reference to my own code. I am sorry I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That definiot saying you need to have scrollable div to see something to happen means you need to have smaller div than content....

```js
$("#home").scroll(function() {
    $("span").css( "display", "inline" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

```css
#home{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

span{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
     something<br>
</div>
<span>Scrolling happening</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I hvae now experiemnted with my own code, and have discovered that each div has to be too small to contain its content. Unfotunately this solution is at odds with my design. I may need to work at a more primitive level or adopt your first recommendation after all! Thanks again.

Comment: Well good luck then :) im now struggling with c#  so i know your pain...